# expression + variable value + normal text in plot maintitle

Tags: r, plot, expression, title

i want to achieve an title in R plot as the following:

```
title = "The significance level you entered is alpha = 0.05 which is often used."
```

In order to get this I split the whole text in little parts, so i finally can write

```
title = paste(part1,part2,part3,part4)
```

The parts are:

```
part1 = "The significance level you entered is"

part2 = expression(alpha)

part3 = object@attribute

part4 = " which is often used."
```

So I'm not able to combine these parts to get my result.

Either the symbol is shown correctly and the part 3 is printed as object@attribute (ant not his value) or the symbol is not shown and the value of the object is printed correctly.

I used `?expression`and `?print`already, but didn't get it

The examples provided in `?plotmath` didn't match my case either.

Comment: Hi before I started this topic I had a look at this thread. But the difference here ist, that i want concatenate symbols, text and value of a variable. The concatenation ist not that problem, but the evaluating of my object attribute. It is always printed out as object@attribute instead of 0.05.

Comment: 1. In my opinion, this is a clearly stated legitimate question. 2. In general, the system of plotmath/expression/bquote usage in R is quite difficult even for experienced users. No single existing SO question on the topic is definitive. 3. Four of the five users who voted to close have zero [r] questions or answers.

Comment: Wow, this was inappropriately marked as a duplicate! The so called duplicate is basically irrelevant to this question. This question is about adding a variable's value to a title not just an 'expression'.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One solution is to use `bquote()`. Use `.()` within `bquote` to get the value of objects or expressions. Here is one example of how that might work:

```
obj = list(foo=0, bar=99, alpha=0.05)
plot(1:10, main=bquote("Significance level is" ~ alpha == .(obj$alpha)))
```

The tilde `~` seems necessary here to convince `bquote` to treat alpha as a plotmath expression.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use this for a `geom_label` in `ggplot2`, you have to wrap this in `as.expression`: `as.expression(bquote("Significance level is" ~ alpha == .(mean(x))))`.

Comment: In my case, I need to start the line with `^1` - superscript number, which bquote seems to dislike. Would be interested in any suggestions (`expression(""^1") is not a solution, since I want to put the content of `text_in_var` and it seems the latter is not easy to do with `expression`

Comment: @JelenaČuklina, try something like this: ```x <- 4; plot(1:10, main=bquote(` `^ .(1 - x) ~ "and some text."))```