# Include variable, comma and greek symbol in an expression

Tags: r, expression, title

I want to create a plot title "Case1, \xi_{DES}", where \xi is the greek letter, DES must be a subscript, and "Case1" is actually stored in a variable. Following

[expression + variable value + normal text in plot maintitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532136/expression-variable-value-normal-text-in-plot-maintitle)

I tried

```
Case="Case1"
x=1:3
y=rnorm(3)
plot(x,y, cex=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, 
pch=16, xlab="degree", ylab=expression(italic(paste("|",hat(F),"|"))),
main=bquote(.(Case) ~ , eta[DES]), col="tomato",log="y")
```

But this doesn't work. The following *sort of* works:

```
plot(x,y, cex=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, 
pch=16, xlab="degree", ylab=expression(italic(paste("|",hat(F),"|"))),
main=bquote(.(Case) ~  eta[DES]), col="tomato",log="y")
```

But I had to eliminate the comma. Why is that? Is there a way to get the title I want in R?

Comment: Try `plot(x,y, cex=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, 
 pch=16, xlab="degree", ylab=expression(italic(paste("|",hat(F),"|"))),
 main=bquote(.(Case)*","* ~  eta[DES]), col="tomato",log="y")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you don't know (it's not easy to find), the documentation is in `help("plotmath")`:

```
par(mar = c(5, 5.5, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(x,y, cex=1.5, cex.lab=1.5, 
     pch=16, xlab="degree", ylab=expression(italic(group("|",hat(F),"|"))),
     main=bquote(.(Case)*","~xi[{DES}]), col="tomato",log="y")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Nice! However, instead than `*` I used `paste` - this is more similar to typical uses of `expression`. In other words, I used `main=bquote(paste(.(Case),", ",eta[DES]))`.

Comment: I don't see a reason to use `paste`, but suit yourself. Note how I used `group` in your `ylab`.

Comment: I didn't notice that. What's the difference between `group` and `paste`? If you have a look at other answers here on Stack Overflow concerning `expression`, using `paste` is often suggested (for example, my `ylab` is taken nearly literally from one of those answers).  Other than that, I'm not partial to `paste`, so if you explain me the advantages of `group` or `*`, I'm more than ok with not using `paste`.

Comment: The difference between `group` and `paste` is explained in the documentation. The output even looks different.