# ggplot: italicize part of dynamically generated title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a dynamically generated title for multiple plots. For example, below are 3 plots titles I'm trying to make.

```
title_list = c("awesome", "amazing", "fantastic")

title suffix = "title"
```

Intended plot titles: ***awesome* title**, ***amazing* title** , ***fantastic* title**.

Notice "title" is not italicized, but "awesome", "amazing" and "fantastic" are. How can I create titles like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bquote` for this. Inside `bquote`, expressions wrapped in `.()` will be evaluated.

```
p = list()
for (i in seq_along(title_list)) {
    p[[i]] = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
        geom_point() +
        labs(title = bquote(italic(.(title_list[i])) ~ .(title_suffix)))
}

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]])
```

[image]

A very related question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20532136/903061).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was curious, I figured it out.

```
plot_title <- substitute(paste(italic(x), "title", sep=" "), list(x=title_list))

p + labs(title=plot_title)
```