# Dynamic subscript for text with an R expression

Tags: r, plot

I want to generate dynamically a subscript for a text in a plot with an R expression. The text of the three points in the plot below should be `$\pi_1$`, `$\pi_2$`, and `$\pi_3$`.

```
lbs <- vector()
for(i in 1:3) lbs <- append(lbs, expression(pi[i]))

plot(1:3)
text(1:3, labels=lbs)
```

The Greek letter appears, but the subscript remains as `i`. I've tried `bquote` as well but without success.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This isn't working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302367/concatenate-strings-and-expressions-in-a-plots-title Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532136/expression-variable-value-normal-text-in-plot-maintitle

Comment: Thanks, but these examples are for a single stamp in the plot (`main` tile `xlab`, `ylab`, etc.) I have not seen one for text in the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
lbs <- vector()
for(i in 1:3) lbs <- append(lbs, parse(text=(paste0("pi[",i,"]"))))

plot(1:3)
text(1:3, labels=lbs)
```

I am sure that there are better solutions but this is working. 
The problem with your code is that everything inside `expression()` is not evaluated. `parse()` evaluates and then returns an expression.[image]