# How to correctly evaluate variable within R tilde expression

Tags: r, syntax

I have a function (`col_grob`) that calls another function (`pal_bar`) with a tilde-notation expression as follows:

```
## plots a colour bar with specified colour intervals
pal_bar <- function(cols) {
  cols <- colorRampPalette(cols)(200)
  par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  plot(1:200, rep(1, 200), col = cols, pch = 15, cex = 1.1, bty = 'n', xaxt = 'n', xlab = '', yaxt = 'n', ylab = '', main="")
}

## calls pal_bar function to plot the bar as a grob, tilde expression
col_grob <- function(pal) {
  g <- ggplotify::as.grob(~pal_bar(pal))
  grid::grid.draw(g)
}
```

I am returned the error "object 'pal' not found" when I run:

```
col_grob(pal = c("red", "blue"))
```

I came across [resources](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) and similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532136/expression-variable-value-normal-text-in-plot-maintitle) but I am not able to solve the issue with my lack of understanding of the evaluation rules. I tried `~pal_bar(I(pal))`, `bquote()` function, and possibly `structure(list(), *)` but do not have sufficient knowledge of each to format the syntax correctly.

How would I get `col_grob(pal = c("red", "blue"))` to plot the desired colour bar for me?
[image]

Comment: Where are your putting the `col_grob` part when you get the error?

Comment: I feel like the issue might be to do with the fact that the plot call in pal_bar doesn't return anything?

Comment: @MrFlick I call col_grob() function independently. The solution below works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
col_grob <- function(pal) {
  txt <- substitute(pal_bar(pal))
  g <- ggplotify::as.grob(as.expression(txt))
  grid::grid.draw(g)
}

col_grob(pal = c("red", "blue"))
```